# Build Errors Using Cocoapods and AFNetworking

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking, cocoapods

First time I have used Cocoapods and so far it has not been a good experience. I am trying t build my project and I am getting errors as below:

[image]

I have googled and googled and googled but have not found anything that is useful. Can anyone please give me any idea as to why this is happening? This is very frustrating as I have spent hours trying to install Cocoapods and am having no luck!

EDIT:
More detailed screenshot of the error

[image]

Comment: Show us the error. Your screenshot just shows a list of errors. Click on an error and then post what it says.

Comment: I have added another screenshot of what the error says

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've seen this issue before when I didn't include the libsqlite3.0.dylib framework in my project. Go to targets - build settings - linked frameworks and libraries - add that framework and build and clean.

[image]